# What is the best Postgres index to perform reverse pattern matching with the pattern being in a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching

*Using Postgres 12.*

I have a table `actions` with pattern matching patterns in a column `action`. I want to `SELECT` all rows where the pattern in the column matches my string. There are thousands of rows and it takes several seconds.

```
CREATE TABLE testing (
    id serial,
    sid uuid NOT NULL,
    action varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO testing (sid, action) 
VALUES 
    ('a2a15c9d-68ba-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'servicea:Get%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-dddd-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'serviceb:Get%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-dddd-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'servicec:Update%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-aaaa-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'serviced:Get%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-baaa-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'servicee:Update%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-68ba-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'servicef:Get%'),
    ('12312333-68ba-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'serviceg:%Items'),
    ('12312333-68ba-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'serviceg:Get%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-68ba-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', '%:%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-dddd-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'serviceb:%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-dddd-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', '%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-abcd-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'serviced:Get%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-baaa-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'serviced:Update%'),
    ('a2a15c9d-68ba-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'servicef:Get%'),
    ('12312333-68ba-46d2-9750-4039a0f65bd4', 'serviceg:Delete%')
;
```

[I created a dummy SQL dump of data for ~1,000,000 rows here for testing purposes.](https://easyupload.io/td7dsx)

The query would be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM testing WHERE 'serviced:GetItem' ~~* testing.action;
```

This works fine for a small table but even with a million rows, it starts to take ~600ms on a MacBook Pro 32GB RAM (no index).

What index do you believe is best for this case?

*p.s. the real use case is similar to AWS Policies and there are even more tables (for action, resources, and for principals) so the latency is crucial for the user-facing API.*

Comment: Actually, 600 ms isn't so bad for a generic regular expression search.

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you think there is an index able to speed this up considering the pattern is in the column?

Comment: `~~*` stands for `ILIKE` and `*` is not a wildcard in `ILIKE`. The query returns no rows.

Comment: @klin sorry fixed using %!

Comment: There is no index that supports the column to the right of the `LIKE` operator. You can try to find an index if you redesign a model to be able to use the column to the left of an operator.